# Pushed to Heroku - Assets(+?) Missing (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I pushed a sample app I was working on to Heroku. Rails 5 - I now notice a lot of issues/differences, a lot I can relate back to an obvious pipeline issue. Majority of the references I see are from R3/R4 but mention putting

```
 config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

in and modifying all `url` to `font-url` or `image-url` - I did that for majority of the fonts, but I'm still seeing blank images, and broken links/missing icons.

Another weird thing is I used JSON Builder to builds out a site.json page - The page itself is actually fine; No issues. However, when I try to limit it with a parameter it immediately returns a 500 error. I've found 4-5 other posts on SO about this, each with a minor amount of replies, and usually they say to do what I mentioned above.

I even tried to go into all of my CSS files cores, and change it to

`font-url('<%= asset_path("mana.eot?#iefix&v=1.3.0") %>')` which also didn't do anything.

I read on Heroku's help site that it has issues due to the MD5 fingerprint and I followed through the steps to connect to the bash to see the file's existance AND the name, but I'm unsure how to really.... do anything about that? Don't they have the same fingerprint when locally compiled/C9/IDE?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of photos missing, you probably have to upload them to AWS or something similar and save the information there. Make an account and follow the instructions, it is pretty straight forward. I had the same problem for my app and that was the solution for me.

In terms of links make sure none of them are localhost:3000 because that will break the links.

Comment: Heroku has the image on it's local instance, but the link is broken. it also can't find jquery etc etc. Basically everything within the assets pipeline.